# How to Reset URL Query Parameters with Next.js 14 App Router without Reloading Page?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, single-page-application, react-query

I'm working on a Next.js 14 application that uses the App Router for navigation and I've encountered a challenge with programmatically updating URL query parameters to reset filters and sorting features in a data table without reloading the page or re-fetching data.

My data table uses manual server-side pagination, sorting, and filters. Changes to pagination, sorting, or filters update the query parameters in the URL, which triggers a new fetch request through the useQuery hook from React Query. The hook takes parameters extracted from the URL query, such as page index, page size, sort by, sort direction, and keyword, and sends a request to the server with this data.

However, when I try to reset the table's filters and sorting to their initial states by updating the URL's query parameters, the previous query parameters persist and do not update as expected.

Here's the relevant part of my component:

```js
// Assuming this is part of a larger component
const DataTable = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const pathname = usePathname()
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()

    // * Search Params
    const queryPageIndex = searchParams.get("page") ? parseInt(searchParams.get("page") as string) : 1
    const queryPageSize = searchParams.get("limit") ? parseInt(searchParams.get("limit") as string) : 10
    const queryPageFilter = searchParams.get("keyword") ? (searchParams.get("keyword") as string) : ""
    const queryPageSortBy = searchParams.get("sortby") ? (searchParams.get("sortby") as string) : ""
    const queryPageSortDirection = searchParams.get("direction") ? (searchParams.get("direction") as string) : ""

    // create query string
    const createQueryString = useCallback(
        (params: Record<string, string | number | null>) => {
            const newSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams?.toString())

            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
                if (value === null || value === undefined || value === "") {
                    newSearchParams.delete(key)
                } else {
                    newSearchParams.set(key, String(value))
                }
            }

            return newSearchParams.toString()
        },
        [searchParams]
    )

    // Code that handles the manual Tanstack Table V8 state, for pagination, global filter, and sorting.
    // ...

    const updateTableAndUrl = useCallback(
        ({
            pageIndex = queryPageIndex - 1,
            pageSize = queryPageSize,
            sorting = sortingState,
            globalFilter = queryPageFilter,
        } = {}) => {
            // Update table state
            setPagination({ pageIndex, pageSize })
            setSortingState(sorting)
            setGlobalFilter(globalFilter)

            // Construct and push new URL
            const queryString = createQueryString({
                page: pageIndex + 1,
                limit: pageSize,
                ...(sorting[0] && { sortby: sorting[0].id, direction: sorting[0].desc ? "desc" : "asc" }),
                ...(globalFilter && { keyword: globalFilter }),
            })
            router.push(`${pathname}?${queryString}`, { scroll: false })
        },
        [createQueryString, pathname, router, queryPageIndex, queryPageSize, sortingState, queryPageFilter]
    )

    // useQuery (I am also using queryClient.prefetchQuery on the page's server component in order to do server-side fetching before page load).
    const { data, isLoading, isError, isSuccess } = useQuery({
        queryKey: [
            "operations",
            queryPageIndex,
            queryPageSize,
            queryPageFilter,
            queryPageSortBy,
            queryPageSortDirection,
        ],
        queryFn: () =>
            fetchOperationsData(
                queryPageIndex - 1,
                queryPageSize,
                queryPageFilter,
                queryPageSortBy,
                queryPageSortDirection
            ),
    })

    // useReactTable instance:
    const tableInstance = useReactTable<OperationType>({
        columns: columns,
        data: data?.results || [],

        // * Hooks:
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
        getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
        getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),

        // * Pagination:
        pageCount: pageCount,
        onPaginationChange: setPagination,
        manualPagination: true,

        // * Sorting:
        manualSorting: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        onSortingChange: handleSortingState,
        enableSortingRemoval: true,

        // * Global Filter:
        manualFiltering: true,
        enableGlobalFilter: true,
        onGlobalFilterChange: (value) => setGlobalFilter(value),

        // * State:
        initialState: {
            pagination: {
                pageIndex: 0,
                pageSize: 10,
            },
            sorting: [],
            globalFilter: "",
        },
        state: {
            pagination: { pageIndex, pageSize },
            sorting: sortingState || [],
            globalFilter: globalFilter,
        },
    })


    // The Issued function, resetting the table state works, but the query parameters stay the same even with a new query string.
    const resetTableAndUrl = () => {
        // Reset table state
        tableInstance.setGlobalFilter("")
        tableInstance.setSorting([])

        // Reset URL to initial state without keyword and sorting parameters
        const newQueryString = createQueryString({
            page: 1,
            limit: 10,
            keyword: null, // Explicitly clear keyword
            sortby: null, // Clear sortby if necessary
            direction: null, // Clear direction if necessary
        })

        router.push(`${pathname}?${newQueryString}`) // Push new URL
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // Update URL query parameters when table state changes
        updateTableAndUrl({
            pageIndex,
            pageSize,
            sorting: sortingState,
            globalFilter,
        })
    }, [pageIndex, pageSize, sortingState, globalFilter, updateTableAndUrl])

    return (
       // ... JSX Content
    )
};
```

Despite calling resetTableAndUrl which attempts to update the URL's query parameters to reflect the reset state, the URL does not update as expected, and the previous query parameters persist.

I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly reset the URL's query parameters using the Next.js 14 App Router in a way that reflects the reset state of the data table without reloading the page.